# how do i $_get with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

im sorry im still new with ajax.i have a problem getting a value with ajax.
i have a set of question from database.i loop them along with the edit button in a table.i can do the $_get fine if i do

```
<a href=somepage.php?qid= echo $row['qid']>link</a>
```

but what i really want to do is edit on the same page without reloading the page.

```
$('.inline.positive.ui.icon.button.edit').click(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url : 'view/addquestion.php',
   type : 'GET', 
   data : {
           'qid' : $row['question_id'],
          },
           success : function(data) {
           alert("Hi, testing");
           }
     });
  });
```

this is my ajax[updated]

i send the value with

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($question)) {
  <div class="ui buttons">
      <button  class="inline positive ui icon button edit" data-qid='<?php $row["question_id"]?>'>
   <i class="edit icon"></i>
 </button>
}
```

i tried to get the question_id for where clause to update that specific question in database.with

```
if (isset($_GET["qid"]))
{
  $qid =  $_GET["qid"];
}
  else
{
  $qid =  0;
}
```

if it helps.im currently using

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js" integrity="sha256-laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

thanks in advance

---

Latest Update :

so i think i get ajax and php abit now.
reason why i cant get the $_GET['qid'] is because the php script is run in server-side which is why i keep getting $_GET['qid'] = 0 as the page did not refresh.(please correct me if im wrong)

as for the ajax.. i update it with new script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".inline.positive.ui.icon.button.edit").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).attr("data-qid");
    $.ajax ({
      url: "view/addquestion.php",
      data: { val : val },
      success: function( data ) {
          alert("Hi, testing" + val);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

the ajax is working now and the alert came out with the correct value.

thanks to apokrypos and nadir(i dont know how to tag people) for helping me with this.

Comment: This line `'qid' => $row['question_id'],`. Here are you building the script from php or are you trying to access a php variable from javascript?

Comment: trying to access php variable from javascript..

Comment: You cannot access php from javascript. Your php code is exectued in your server, while your javascript code is executed on the client (user web browser)

Comment: ah im sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the differences between server-side and client-side scripting. All server side scripts are executed and finished before any JavaScript is loaded. You can't access any PHP variables from JavaScript simply because PHP is not running on the same place JavaScript is. You'll have to pass the variables through your HTML to the client side where JavaScript can access them.

Example:

**PHP Loop**

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($question)): ?>
  <div class="ui buttons">
      <button  class="inline positive ui icon button edit" data-qid='<?= $row["question_id"]?>'> 
         <i class="edit icon"></i>
       </button>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**jQuery Ajax**

```
$('.inline.positive.ui.icon.button.edit[data-qid]').click(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url : 'view/addquestion.php',
   type : 'GET', 
   data : {
           'qid': $(this).attr("data-qid"),
          },
           success : function(data) {
           }
     });
  });
```

Comment: i tried this.but i still cant get the value with $_GET["qid"].can u explain or help me how can i get the qid value?

Comment: I think I had the wrong syntax in the `data:..` part of jQuery. Updated

Comment: i still get $_GET['qid'] = 0

Comment: I'm looking at your edited question and you have `data-qid='<?php $row["question_id"]?>'` instead of `data-qid='<?= $row["question_id"]?>'` is that a typo?